# How to create a short-cut to change font style?

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2007

I am using Microsoft OneNote 2007 quite a bit.

In my notes I often type some code sample. I then, for readability, format them with the `Consolas` font. Is there a way to create a keyboard shortcuts to switch back and forth between `Consolas` and `Calibri`? Two separe keyboard shortcuts would be fine too.

Comment: You can take a look at AutoHotkey to [send](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) the required keystrokes to the program.